# class: Configuration not found on when simulating Hadoop YARN SLS

Tags: java, git, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to simulate Hadoop YARN SLS (**Scheduling Load Simulator**) with the sources given in [Hadoop's GitHub](https://github.com/apache/hadoop) and the SLS source files are located in *[REF-1]*.

- Here the step I have done :

  1. Using VMWARE as the Host.
  2. Using Ubuntu 14.04
  3. Installing Hadoop v 2.6.0 [*REF-2*]

     - User : **hduser** | group : **hadoop**
  4. Installing any needed packages (e.g. maven)
  5. Get the clonning file of **Hadoop's GitHub** *[REF-1]*

     - Syntax : `git clone https://git.apache.org/hadoop.git`
     - Result : `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop$`
  6. I made the changes inside directory `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$`

FYI : I used the codes from MaxinetSLS *[REF-3]* as the way I compile the source files. The SLS source files can be downloaded by using this syntax in Linux : `git clone https://github.com/wette/netSLS.git`. By default, I can run this program with no error. The SLS Simulator can work perfectly.

- From **MaxiNetSLS**'s source files, I copied this files below into my work in `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$` :

  1. `netSLS/generator` > `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$`
  2. `netSLS/html` > `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$`
  3. `netSLS/sls.sh` > `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$`
  4. `netSLS/sls/hadoop/` > `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-sls$`

Then, I modified some files as follows.

**netSLS/sls.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function print_usage {
  echo -e "usage: sls.sh TraceFile"
  echo -e
  echo -e "Starts SLS with the given trace file."
}

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  print_usage
  exit 1
fi

TRACE_FILE=$(realpath $1)

if [[ ! -f ${TRACE_FILE} ]]; then
  echo "File not found: ${TRACE_FILE}"
  print_usage
  exit 1
fi

cd hadoop-sls

OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="/tmp/sls"
mkdir -p ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}

ARGS="-inputsls ${TRACE_FILE}"
ARGS+=" -output ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
ARGS+=" -printsimulation"

mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="${ARGS}"
```

---

**`hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-sls/pom.xml$`**

- [REF-4]

---

**`hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$ nano hadoop-sls/hadoop/etc/hadoop/sls-runner.xml`**

- [REF-5]

---

- Next step, I try to :

  1. Compile the script using `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-sls$ mvn compile`

     - *Compiled with no error* (mvn_compile_perfect.jpg).
  2. Run the program using `hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/hadoop-tools$ ./sls.sh generator/small.json`

     - **Got the error here** (error_json_compile.jpg). :(

---

Until now, I have went through some information related with similar problems I faced [REF-6] and tried it, but I still get the same problem. I guess I think the problem is in the `~/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-sls/pom.xml` I mistakenly modified. I have lack of knowledge with Linux Environment. :(

---

**References** : http://1drv.ms/21zcJIH (txt file)
*Cannot post more than 2 links in my post. :(